# EMV application selection using AID

Tags: smartcard-reader, apdu, emv

I am trying to read a Visa Credit Card, using the command:

```
00 A4 04 07 A0 00 00 00 03 10 10
```

but I'm getting this response

```
61 2E
```

I am unable to understand this response, because the EMV Book 1 says (pag 146):

```
6A 81 : command not supported
90 00 or 62 83 command is successfull
```

Any help on how to proceed now? What I'm missing? What should I do?

Thanks.

Comment: Is the command (as written) missing P2?

Answer (score 5):

Found the issue, posted here in case anyone runs in a similar issue:

From EMV Book #1, pag #114:

> The GET RESPONSE command is issued by the TTL to obtain available data
>   from the ICC when processing case 2 and 4 commands. It is employed
>   only when the T=0 protocol type is in use.

So, the next command to send in this case is:

```
OO C0 00 00 2E
```

in order to receive the actual data.

Comment: Thanks for reporting back. If the card supports T=1 I would strongly recommend you to use that. You can use the ATR to check if the card supports the protocol.